# How to place Sub or Function headers inside of the routine using MZ-Tools

Tags: vba

I noticed that many SO users are running MZ-Tools, so I figured I would give it a shot. I just installed MZ-Tools 8.0 and I'm playing with the Insert Headers tool. The tool inserts the header text above the Sub/Function declaration line, but I want the header to be just below the declaration line.

Currently:

```
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: RunTimeChecks
' Purpose: Lorum Ipsum Statement
' Procedure Kind: Function
' Procedure Access: Public
' Author: cwl57966
' Date: 11/7/2017
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Function RunTimeChecks()
   '......Do Something Here.....
End Function
```

What I want:

```
Function RunTimeChecks()
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure Name: RunTimeChecks
' Purpose: Lorum Ipsum Statement
' Procedure Kind: Function
' Procedure Access: Public
' Author: cwl57966
' Date: 11/7/2017
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
   '......Do Something Here.....
End Function
```

Comment: FWIW such "headings" are very distracting and objectively redundant - useful comments say "why", not "what". Source control says "who" and "when"... the only useful bit here is the "purpose" part, which the function's name *should* accurately convey anyway. In any case if the feature isn't configurable, it seems you need to make a feature request for such a setting.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running MZ8 on the same box that had multiple side-by-side Office installs?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes just playing around with it. There are some Parameters you can use for placement but I haven't figured it out yet. I see so many comments on here about the tool, I figured someone would know what parameter to use there

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, same machine. Only Rubberduck doesn't work on it. This machine has been running for years with multiple office installs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little tickbox below to set this option to inject below the declaration.
[image]